# Importing GitHub repository into a specific folder

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have a GitHub repository that I've created by copying content of a specific folder.

Now I have installed GitHub Desktop and I would like to directly connect this directory to my GitHub repository instead of re-downloading and creating a copy.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before switching to GitHub Desktop, you should prepare the environment for that folder, in order to be linked to the remote repository:

```
cd /local/path/to/folder
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>
git fetch
git switch -m master
```

Then you can open GitHub Desktop and [add a local repository](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-to-projects/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop) (the folder you just configured)

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/desktop/add-local-repository-windows.png]